# unable to stop postgres after enabling gzip on archive wal log

Tags: database, postgresql

I Have enabled the gzip on archived WAL files. However after that Im unable to stop the database.
I believe its wait for all sessions to stop, however following PID 20100 never stops as pg_xlog/000000010000002D000000A4 was never been created. 
How do I solve this?

```
-bash-4.1$ ps x
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
19807 ?        S      0:00 sshd: postgres@pts/2
19808 pts/2    Ss     0:00 -bash
19923 pts/2    S      0:00 /opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/postgres
19924 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: logger process
19926 ?        Ss     0:02 postgres: checkpointer process
19927 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: writer process
19928 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: wal writer process
19929 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
19930 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: archiver process   archiving 000000010000002D000000A4
19931 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: stats collector process
20050 pts/2    S+     0:00 /bin/bash /opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql
20052 pts/2    S+     0:00 /opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql.bin
20055 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: postgres sorriso [local] idle
20059 ?        S      0:00 sshd: postgres@pts/5
20060 pts/5    Ss     0:00 -bash
20100 ?        S      0:00 sh -c gzip < pg_xlog/000000010000002D000000A4 > /mnt/nfs/archive/000000010000002D000000A4
20101 ?        D      0:00 gzip
20113 pts/5    R+     0:00 ps x
-bash-4.1$ pg_ctl stop
waiting for server to shut down............................................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
HINT: The "-m fast" option immediately disconnects sessions rather than
waiting for session-initiated disconnection.
-bash-4.1$ pg_ctl stop
waiting for server to shut down............................................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
HINT: The "-m fast" option immediately disconnects sessions rather than
waiting for session-initiated disconnection.
-bash-4.1$ echo $PGDATA
/opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/data
-bash-4.1$ pg_ctl stop -m smart
waiting for server to shut down............................................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
HINT: The "-m fast" option immediately disconnects sessions rather than
waiting for session-initiated disconnection.
-bash-4.1$ pg_ctl stop -m fast
waiting for server to shut down............................................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
-bash-4.1$
```

Comment: why dont you `kill -9 20100`?..

Comment: Will that create issue if last change is not archived ?

Comment: I suppose you added gzip to `archive_command`?.. Dunno to tell the truth, but after you shutdown db, you can always just gzip wal to `/mnt/nfs/archive/` manually

Comment: Vao, I realized bigger issue. I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113690/wal-archive-hangs-in-postgres-when-gzip-is-used