# WAL Archive hangs in postgres when gzip is used

Tags: database, postgresql

I have enabled the WAL Archiving with following archive command:

```
wal_keep_segments = 32
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'gzip < %p > /mnt/nfs/archive/%f'
```

and on Slave I have restore command as:

```
restore_command = 'gunzip < /mnt/nfs/archive/%f > %p'
archive_cleanup_command = '/opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_archivecleanup -d /mnt/nfs/archive %r'
```

on Master I could see that many files are stuck. around 327 files are yet to be archived. Ideally it should be only 32 only.

the px command shows:

```
-bash-4.1$ ps x
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3302 ?        S      0:00 /opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/postgres -D /opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/data
 3304 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: logger process
 3306 ?        Ss     0:09 postgres: checkpointer process
 3307 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: writer process
 3308 ?        Ss     0:06 postgres: wal writer process
 3309 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
 3311 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: stats collector process
 3582 ?        S      0:00 sshd: postgres@pts/1
 3583 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
 3628 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: archiver process   archiving 000000010000002D000000CB
 3673 ?        S      0:00 sh -c gzip < pg_xlog/000000010000002D000000CB > /mnt/nfs/archive/000000010000002D000000CB
 3674 ?        D      0:00 gzip
 3682 ?        S      0:00 sshd: postgres@pts/0
 3683 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
 4070 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: postgres postgres ::1(34561) idle
 4074 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: postgres sorriso ::1(34562) idle
 4172 pts/0    S+     0:00 vi postgresql.conf
 4192 pts/1    R+     0:00 ps x
-bash-4.1$ ls | wc -l
327
-bash-4.1$
```

Comment: `wal_keep_segments` specifies the minimum number of WAL files to be kept.

Comment: no, I believe it it maximum :) cos if your transaction is bigger then `wal_keep_segments`*16M replication brakes

Comment: @VaoTsun makes sense to check the documentation

Comment: maybe you want `zcat` instead of `gunzip` ?

Comment: I stop the slave and archive processes started arching files to shared location. Hence it looks like the file locking issue between Master and slave.... when gzip from master try to write and gunzip trying to read at the same time. this happens with gzip and gunzip only. when I used normal cp command it works. How do I handle this conflicts ?

Comment: @zerkms checked :) now I have a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116292/wal-keep-segments-why-minimum-not-maximum

Comment: @VaoTsun on all my servers I would say that I never see it to be equal or less `wal_keep_segments` files, it's always more :-) I don't have an answer for your question though

Comment: @zerkms hm, and if you temporarily set it 50 more?..

Comment: @zerkms would you possible confuse this parameter to be a slave one?.. Cos it is set on master, no slave (Sending Server(s) Parameter)

Comment: no no the no. of WAL file is not an issue. its all because, gunzip start reading the file as soon as gzip writes the empty file. As postgreSQL Archive process auto generate the file name sequence and then look for pg_xlog dir for file with the name. I just modified my command to check if file exist in pg_xlog then only start gzip. archive_command = 'test -e %p && gzip < %p > /mnt/nfs/archive/%f' .. thats it, it solved the file lock issue.

Comment: `wal_keep_segments` has **nothing to do with this** and is *not required or useful*. It's only for if you're doing streaming replication. Ignore that parameter if you're only doing archive based replication.

Answer (score 0):

`gzip` and `gunzip` without flags expect to work with files, compressing or uncompressing them in-place. You're trying to use them as stream processors. That's not going to work.

You want to use `gzip -c` and `zcat` (or `gunzip -c`) to tell them to use stdio.

Additionally, though, you should probably use a simple script as the `archive_command` that:

- Writes with `gzip -c` to a temp file
- Moves the temp file to the final location with `mv`

This ensures that the file is not read by the replica until it's fully written by the master.

Also, unless the master and replica are sharing the same network file system (or are both on the same host), you might actually need to use `scp` or similar to transfer the archive files. The `restore_command` uses paths *on the replica*, not on the master, so unless the replica server can access the WAL archive via NFS/CIFS/etc, you're going to need to copy the files.

Comment: @wildplasser Yeah. I was surprised (and surprised you didn't just post an answer). Figured it needed to be made more obvious.

Comment: I thought it was rather obvious, too... (and why didnt the OP check the decompressed files's sizes?)

Comment: This really goes to show, IMO, how bad an idea it is for us (PostgreSQL community) to give users a bucket of miscellaneous parts, a few hints in the manual, and a screwdriver, then tell them to go build ... something. We really need a canned tool that addresses the common cases well. It looks like PgBarman will soon be able to take care of much of this, thankfully, but it's still not exactly *simple* when they have to configure passwordless key-based ssh, etc. Streaming replication with slots will help.

Comment: I don't think that keeping things under the hood will help. Not in all cases. There will always be cases like disk-full, network stuff, disappearing NAS disks, etc. A basic understanding of the unix toolset will be still be needed. (such as in this case) But "works out of the box; don't tinker" will work *initially*

Comment: @wildplasser I agree. In particular, failover without STONITH is asking for trouble, and there's no universal STONITH solution. Similarly, some people will want to replicate between two hosts in the same datacenter, direct from one to the other; some will want to via external archiving used for PITR too, some will want to store archives in S3 then age them into AWS Glacier, etc etc etc. The matrix of configurations is huge, and most of them are sensible for someone to want. We should still try to provide simple(r) answers for some common ones though.

Comment: Final comment: Postgres's PITR very much resembles Ingres's "journal" management. Even the %f %p parameters are the same, IIRC. (or was it %c ? )